# How can I prove the following property of bounded linear operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

How can I prove property (iv) of  bounded linear operators in the following picture?

[image]

Any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: so you're interested in (iv) and you post all four parts of the problem? You've got 500 in rep, isn't it time to learn MathJax?

Comment: I know MathJax  .... but sometimes I do not have enough time to write ..... sorry @zhw.

Comment: $\|CAx\| \le \|C\|\|Ax\| \le \|C\|\|A\|\|x\|$ implies that $CA$ is bounded and $\|CA\| \le \|C\|\|A\|$

Comment: And why CA is in $L(H_{1},H_{3})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: your intuition should tell you iv) must ultimately depend on the $H_i$ norms and the triangular inequality.

Expand $||A+B||$ into $$\sup_{||x|| = 1} {||A(x)+B(x)||} \le \sup_{||x|| = 1} {||A(x)||+||B(x)||} = \sup_{||x|| = 1} {||A(x)||} +\sup_{||x|| = 1} {||B(x)||} = ||A|| + ||B||$$.

Comment: A very short ring :( .... could you provide more details ?

Comment: Okay, see my edit. How about it?

Comment: I will see your edit but after 3 hours but could you please check this question for me if you have time ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523207/how-to-prove-the-following-property-of-the-norm

Comment: The OP asked about (iv). You answered (iii).

Comment: $\sup_{\|x\|=1}(\|Ax\|+\|Bx\|) \le \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|+\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Bx\|$

Comment: Really I asked about (iv) not (iii) @cronos2